# Stored procedure taking long time to execute in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[delivary1] 
   @dedate nvarchar(100), 
   @carid nvarchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @transid int
    declare @status int
    declare @count int,
            @currentdate nvarchar(50)

    select @currentdate = GETDATE()

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select @count = count(*) 
    from Transaction_tbl 
    where TBarcode = @carid

    if @count=0
    begin
       return -1
    end
    else
    begin
       select @status = t1.Status  
       from Transaction_tbl t1 
       where t1.TBarcode = @carid

       if @status = 4
       begin
          select @transid = t.transactID 
          from Transaction_tbl t 
          where t.TBarcode = @carid

          update Transaction_tbl 
          set DelDate = '' + @currentdate + '', Status=5 
          where TBarcode = @carid

          update KHanger_tbl 
          set Delivered = 1 
          where transactid = @transid

          return 4
       end

       if @status = 5
       begin
          return 5
       end

       if @status=0
       begin
          return 0
       end

       if @status=1
       begin
          return 1
       end

       if @status = 2
       begin
          return 2
       end

       if @status = 3
       begin
          return 3
       end
    end
end
```

My database has more than 10 lack of records. Sometimes this takes a long time to execute..

Is there any way to write this stored procedure any simpler than this way?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Execution plan of my stored procedure

[image]

Comment: is it only sometimes it take too long? or is it always taking too long to execute ?

Comment: sir..always taking long time..

Comment: can you show the execution plan then ?

Comment: yes sir..i will edit my question with execution plan

Comment: You might want to add the missing indexes that the execution plan suggests and measure performance after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to return the value for status, it just doent make any sense,

also add the missing index which suggests you will get around 93% improvement in your performance.

[image]

you can write this procedure with an OUTPUT parameter something like this...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[delivary1] 
    @dedate nvarchar(100), 
    @carid  nvarchar(100),
    @status INT OUTPUT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @transid int, @count int,@currentdate nvarchar(50)

     SET @currentdate = GETDATE();


    select @count = count(*) from Transaction_tbl where TBarcode = @carid

    if (@count = 0)
       begin
          SET @status = -1;
       end
    else
      begin
          select @status = t1.[Status]  from Transaction_tbl t1 where t1.TBarcode = @carid

            if (@status = 4)
              begin
                select @transid = t.transactID 
                  from Transaction_tbl t 
                 where t.TBarcode = @carid

                update Transaction_tbl 
                       set DelDate = '' + @currentdate + ''
                         , [Status] = 5 
                 where TBarcode = @carid

                update KHanger_tbl 
                   set Delivered=1 
                 where transactid = @transid
              end
      end
END
```

### How to add Missing Index

Go to your execution plan Right Click where it is showing Missing Index, and the click on the `Missing Index Details`

[image]

And it will Give you the Index Definition in a new query window that SQL Server thinks will help it to improve the performance of this query. All you need to do now is Just execute the Statement and it will create the index for you.

### Index Definition

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery1.sql - ALI-PC.AdventureWorks2008R2 (My Server\UserName (59))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 95.7414%.
*/

/*
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] ([TerritoryID],[ShipMethodID],[SubTotal],[Freight])
INCLUDE ([SalesOrderNumber],[CustomerID])
GO
*/
```

Comment: sir i must need to take return value..in code depend on return value i am showing some messages

Comment: in which field i have to add index??

Comment: @user3252014 What about you read the execution plan you copied and pasted? YOu may be surprised but it tell you which fields are missing.

Comment: @user3252014 Have a look now, I have explained how you can add the missing index.

Answer (score 3):

Well, lets get serious.

- Your end of the SP is redundant, jsut return @status.
- The update is badly programming in using string for the date, but that is not relevant forspeed.
- The speed is just in the Select. Interesting enough you miss an index which is shown in the screenshot you sent - which tells me you never bothered to even look at it before posting.

Please start considering indices and planning them. In your case you defintiely miss an index.